# Why is the VS Code GitHub Copilot extension overriding all other Code Actions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, github-copilot

I have a problem I used the normal code actions menu quite often (pressing the lightbulb or it's shortcut).
But after installing Copilot and signing up, my normal options are replaced by "Modify using Copilot".
I really don't want to write "extract to method" every time i highlight something and wants it in its own method...

Any suggestions to how I can get both ?

[image]

**Update:** I just updated my plugin, and now it shows it correctly:
[image]

Comment: For me, instead of the lightbulb, I can right click, select "Refactor...," and I get the same code actions menu as the lightbulb.

Comment: so if you disable the copilot extension(s) and reload the window, the regular code actions do show up in the same spot shown in your screenshot?

Comment: @starball now it shows it correctly, i had an update to the plugin this morning.

Comment: what version of the extension do you have installed now?

Comment: @starball v1.138.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue went away for the asker after they updated to v1.138.0 of the GitHub Copilot VS Code extension.

I tried looking for a matching issue ticket but couldn't find one. Maybe it'll show up in the issue tracker later or maybe never. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-copilot-release/issues?q=is%3Aissue+label%3Acode-actions+is%3Aclosed.