VSCode Copilot plugin hides refactoring tools. How to unhide?
Running VSCode 1.8.7.2 with the Copilot plugin on a Mac.  I know that VSCode has the usual refactoring tools (change method signature, rename method, etc).  However, when I right-click on a method name and choose "refactor" from the context menu, I don't see any of these tools.  All I see are the Copilot refactoring tools.  Is there any way to show both the Copilot refactoring tools as well as the normal VSCode refactoring tools?


I highlighted a method name and right-clicked on it.  When the context menu came up, I clicked on "Refactor."  I expected to see the normal VSCode refactoring tools in addition to the Copilot refactoring tools.  However, I only saw the Copilot tools.

I wonder if copilot extension is "taking over" the regular refactor menu? what if you disable the copilot extension? what do you see?

calls to mind https://stackoverflow.com/q/77542346/11107541. I wonder if there's any relation, or if this is a duplicate.
